# Is there a better way to implement setTimeout() than this?

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

`typingEffect()` iterates through an array of strings that type out on the screen like a chatbot. I originally put `typedMessage.textContent = "";` inside `typingFunction()` to simplify things, but it was really hard to time the clearing text feature with how long some of the strings are.

I tried to change the timing around, but because the loop function can only be set to one set time(I think), I couldn't make it work.

Is there a better way to write this so it's more repeatable, while being able to manipulate the timing of the `typedMessage.textContent = "";`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const typedMessage = document.querySelector("div");
const messageArray = ["Welcome to your new chatBuddy!", "I want to ask you a few questions...", 
                      "Some of them might be kind of weird..", "But, hey... we're pals, right?!", 
                      "After all, my name is ChatBuddy, so...let's do this!", "Would you rather have no arms or no legs?"];

/**
 * function typingEffect()
 * iterates through messageArray[] to type out messages
 * setTimeout feature to iterate through characters/clear text
 * @param {string} message 
 * @param {string} item
 * @param {integer} i 
 * @returns 
 */
    const typingEffect = (message, item, i = 0) => {
    message.textContent += item[i];
    if (i === item.length - 1) {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => { 
        typingEffect(message, item, i + 1)
    }, 30);
}

typingEffect(typedMessage, messageArray[0]);
setTimeout(() => {
    typedMessage.textContent = "";
}, 3000)
setTimeout(() => {
    typingEffect(typedMessage, messageArray[1]);
}, 3100)
setTimeout(() => {
    typedMessage.textContent = "";
}, 7000)
setTimeout(() => {
    typingEffect(typedMessage, messageArray[2]);
}, 7100)
setTimeout(() => {
    typedMessage.textContent = "";
}, 11000)
setTimeout(() => {
    typingEffect(typedMessage, messageArray[3]);
}, 11100)
setTimeout(() => {
    typedMessage.textContent = "";
}, 15000)
```

Comment: Wow, no idea you could do this with css. Appreciate it!

Comment: First of, CSS is NOT the right tool (as you eventually figured out reading the link posted by Yogi) for your task. Secondly, your premises in the function's JSDoc `* iterates through messageArray[] to type out messages` and `* @param {string} message` are incorrect - which blurs the actual problem you're desiring to solve - making it unclear.  Should your function accept an Array argument? Or a string? Or both? Also `message` should be a {HTMLElement}, not a {string}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, create two functions, one that types messages and the other that accepts an Array and passes each message to the first one after a timeout of 2sec:

```js
const typingText = (elem, txt, done = () => {}) => {
  let i = 0;
  elem.textContent = ""; // Clear before typing!
  const next = () => {
    elem.textContent += txt[i];
    if (i === txt.length - 1) return done();
    i += 1;
    setTimeout(next, 30);
  };
  next(); // Start!
};

const typingArray = (elem, arr, done = () => {}) => {
  let i = 0; 
  const next = () => {
     typingText(elem, arr[i], () => {
       if (i === arr.length - 1) return done();
       i += 1;
       setTimeout(next, 2000);
     });
  };
  next(); // Start!
};

const elDiv = document.querySelector("div");
const messages = [
  "Welcome to your new chatBuddy!",
  "I want to ask you a question...",
  "Can you combine the two functions into one?"
];
typingArray(elDiv, messages, () => { console.log("All done!"); });
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Both function have a `done` function that calls on completion, text typed for the first one, and after all the array is typed - for the second function.

For homework (since the two functions are pretty similar) you can try to convert them into a single *blueprint* function that accepts either a String or an Array of Strings; and use accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed the @param{}. From my understanding, this solves the issue in running into timing, too. It has a 2-second timer between them, so this gives me the freedom to write whatever I want. Also, ```done = ()``` as a parameter is new to me. I'm thinking it's a more clear way to write ```return``` stating that this execution is "done". Thanks for your input.

Comment: Just re-read you're explanation at the end and I think I have it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bryan `x = () => {}` (assigning an empty function to a variable or argument) is known as: noop function which in our case will serve as a callback function, allowing to pass any custom function, like we did above for the logging in: `typingArray(elDiv, messages, () => { console.log("All done!"); });`. In short by passing a third argument function, such will replace the done noop - and execute without errors in `return done();`

Comment: Awesome! Cheers for what you do.